# Using node-xmpp to show a user as online through Adium

Tags: node.js, xmpp, node-xmpp, adium

I am running a local ejabberd 2 server and I have 2 users. `jeremy@pbx.dev` and `billy@pbx.dev`. Both users have each other on their rosters added from the ejabberd admin webportal.

I'm using adium on OSX logged in with the `jeremy` account. I would like to use the node console and see the `billy` account show as online allowing me to message billy from adium, and message jeremy from the node REPL.

```
var Client = require('node-xmpp-client'),
    ltx = require('node-xmpp-core').ltx;

var client = new Client({jid: 'billy@pbx.dev', password: 'password'});

client.on('online', function(data) {
    console.log('Connected as ' + data.jid.user + '@' + data.jid.domain + '/' + data.jid.resource)
    var presence = new ltx.Element('presence', { type: 'available' }).c('show').t('chat');
    client.send(presence);
});

client.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
    console.log('RECEIVED STANZA', stanza);
});

client.on('offline', function () {
    console.log('Client is offline');
});

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Client is connected');
});

// log in
client.connect();

var message = new ltx.Element('message',{to: 'jeremy@pbx.dev', type: 'chat'}).c('body').t('sup?');

// send message
client.send(message);

var roster = new ltx.Element('iq',{id: 'roster_0',type: 'get'}).c('query', { xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});

// get roster
client.send(roster);

// log out
client.end();
```

I can send messages from the billy account to the jeremy account, and vice versa just fine. However, I can't see that billy is online from Adium though.

To double test this, I created a third user called "asterisk". I added "asterisk" to the jeremy roster, and then set this user up through Asterisk. I *can* see this user online through Adium.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some digging I got it working. I came across [Simple XMPP](https://github.com/simple-xmpp/node-simple-xmpp) which wraps the node-xmpp and got it all working.

The issue that I had was that my billy user didn't accept the subscription or subscribe to the jeremy user. Here's the whole thing

```
xmpp.connect({jid: 'billy@pbx.dev', password: 'password', host: 'pbx.dev',port: 5222});
xmpp.on('online', function(data) { 
  xmpp.acceptSubscription('jeremy@pbx.dev'); 
  xmpp.subscribe('jeremy@pbx.dev');
  xmpp.getRoster();
});

xmpp.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
  var rosterRequest = stanza.name == 'iq' && stanza.attrs.type == 'result' && stanza.attrs.id == 'roster_0'
  if(rosterRequest) {
    var buddies = stanza.children[0].children;
    // do stuff with buddies
  }
});

// change status with
xmpp.setPresence('away', 'BRB AFK IRL');
```

I'd recommend digging through the simple xmpp code to learn a bit more. It's pretty small and really just wraps the node-xmpp.